# Open a file for each element of an array in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to this.  What I am trying to do is to create a file for each element in an array.
For example if and array has three elements ["a","b","c"], i want to be able to create three files called a.txt, b.txt, and c.txt.

Thanks

Comment: And ? What's your problem actually ?

Comment: `files = [open(name+'.txt','w') for name in name_list]`. Do the same to close the files with `close`. BTW it's not an array, it's a list

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over your list and open each file:

```
for s in ["a","b","c"]:
    with open(s+".txt", "w") as f:
        pass   # will create an empty file
```

Comment: People are rude. I think your solution meets the requirements. Maybe they do not want you to answer since the OP doesn't follow SO's guidelines on how to ask a question

Comment: BTW why open with `w+`? Explain it in the answer. Also explain why you use `with`

Comment: Yes unnecessary, 'w' would be sufficient - 'w' creates if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Your original answer was `with open("a"+".txt", "w") as f:` I think that's why you got the down-vote. I am not the one who down-voted your answer so I don't know. However, now you have edited and corrected your answer and now it looks like I just copied your answer even though I answered before your correction.

Comment: Understood, though feedback would have helped, and easily fixed when I noticed it myself. Down voting for a simple oversight seems a little counter-productive.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create and name a file for each element in your `list`, you have to loop through your list like this:

```
for i in ["a","b","c"]:
    with open(i +".txt", "w+") as f:
        f.write("Hello")
```

This will create 3 files `a.txt`, `b.txt` and `c.txt` with the string "Hello" in each file.

Comment: Thank you.  This is what I needed.

Comment: @HamidG Great! I am glad I could help. Please click the  answer as the accepted correct answer.